# Hitting set problem and Vertex Cover

Tags: np-complete, reductions, vertex-cover

In Chapter 8 Question 5 of Kleinberg and Tardos, the problem is as follows:

> Consider a set $A = \{a_1, \ldots , a_n\}$ and a collection $B_1, B_2, \ldots , B_m$ of subsets of $A$ (i.e., $B_i \subseteq A$ for each $i$).
>
> We say that a set $H \subseteq A$ is a *hitting set* for the collection $B_1, B_2, \ldots , B_m$ if $H$ contains at least one element from each $B_i$ — that is, if $H \cap B_i$
> is not empty for each $i$ (so $H$ "hits" all the sets $B_i$).
>
> We now define the *Hitting Set Problem* as follows. We are given a set $A = \{a_1, \ldots , a_n\}$ and a collection $B_1, B_2, \ldots , B_m$ of subsets of $A$, and a number $k$.
> We are asked: Is there a hitting set $H \subseteq A$ for $B_1, B_2, \ldots , B_m$ so that the size of $H$ is at most $k$?

The solution to the problem is given [here](https://github.com/mathiasuy/Soluciones-Klenberg/blob/master/chapter_08/problem%20(5).pdf).
However, I am not sure I follow the reduction.

Consider the set $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$, and $B_1 = \{1, 2, 3\}$. The graph constructed from the solution would have edges between $\{1, 2\}$, $\{2, 3\}$, and $\{1, 3\}$ — essentially forming a triangle. Then $H$ can be any of the elements in $\{1, 2, 3\}$, since any element would "hit" $B_1$. However, as for vertex cover, the smallest vertex cover is of size 2, since one vertex is only adjacent to two vertices, and there are three vertices.

So we have what seems to be an asymmetric reduction where the minimum size of $H$ (1) is not equal to the minimum size of vertex cover (2) for this graph.

How should I reconcile this apparent discrepancy?

Comment: The link provides a reduction from vertex cover to hitting set. The input to the reduction is an instance of vertex cover, and the output is an instance of hitting set. Your counterexample goes the other way.

Comment: Given a triangle on $\{1,2,3\}$, the corresponding hitting set problem has three sets $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}$. The objective value is 2 in both cases.

Comment: Thanks @YuvalFilmus for the clarification. So for reduction from vertex cover to hitting set, the hitting set problem does not have the freedom to choose its k? My understanding is that solving one problem would enable us to solve the other, but it seems that there is not a one-to-one relationship between the types of input problem (vertex cover) to the target problem (hitting set)? In other words, certain hitting set problem do not have corresponding vertex cover problem that can reduce to it? Thank you very much for the clarification again.

Comment: A reduction from vertex cover to hitting set is an efficient function whose input is an instance of vertex cover and whose output is an instance of hitting set. Apart from being efficient, all we require is that the input is a Yes instance iff the output is a Yes instance. There are *no* other constraints.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is all clear now.